# exec with a variable filedescriptor

Tags: shell, exec

Why isn't this possible and what's the best way around it:

```
#!/bin/sh
desc=5; file=/etc/passwd
exec "$desc"<"$file" #the variable filedescriptor is the problem
```

I'd rather not `eval`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, as to why it's not possible, you wouldn't want:

```
echo "$text">file
```

To stop working if `$x` happens to be a number.

You'd need to do:

```
eval 'exec '"$desc"'< "$file"'
```

For the shell to evaluate the `exec 5< "$file"` code. `eval` is OK as long as you're careful to only expand the things that need to be expanded (and that those expansions are safe) in its arguments (here by using strong quotes for everything but `$desc`). What would be wrong would be something like <strike>`eval "exec $desc< $file"`</strike> where the content of `$file` is given for the shell to evaluate as shell code.

With `zsh`, you can also use the `sysopen` builtin in the `zsh/system` module:

```
zmodload zsh/system
sysopen -u "$desc" -r -- "$file"
```

In: `zsh`, `bash` and `ksh93`

```
exec {desc}>&-
```

would work at closing the fd stored in `$desc`, but in

```
exec {desc}> file
```

The shell allocates a fd above 10 and *assigns* it to `$desc`. That can't be used to open `file` on the fd that was stored in `$desc` beforehand.

Note that `exec >&"$desc"` works because there's no ambiguity there... except in `zsh` and recent versions of `bash` that have a `>&` operator to redirect both stdout and stderr to a file (like in `csh`), and where `echo something >& "$file"` works only as long as `$file` is not numerical.

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding your first statement. Wouldn't you _want_ `$x` precisely to be a number? Or is there a typo?